# What are these clips from my wardrobe panel called?

Tags: doors, hinges

These plastic "clips" broke and fell off of the top of my wardrobe panels.

[image: broken clip]
<sup>Click to embiggen</sup>

Now my panels are wobbling and go off rail. What are they called? There are so many variations of them online and it's hard to zero in on which one they are.

Here's a picture of where it was placed and what it looked like prior.

[image: plastic part in place on working carrier]

Comment: is that picture upside down?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's called the top guide. I believe I found the one that goes to your door:

https://daiek.com/sliding-mirror-doors/

[image]